# linux driver installation error - “/lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5/build: No such file or directory. Stop.”

Tags: linux, compiling, drivers

I got an error

```
/lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
```

while installing `moxa` driver, following is the shell screen shot.

```
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# pwd
/root/moxa/mxu11x0/driver
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# ls
Makefile  mxu1110_fw.h  mxu1130_fw.h  mxu1131_fw.h  mxu1150_fw.h  mxu1151_fw.h  mxu11x0.c  mxu11x0.h  usb-serial.h
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# make clean
rm -f *.o
rm -f .*.o.cmd
rm -f *.symvers
rm -rf ./.tmp_versions
rm -f mxu11x0.mod*
rm -f .mxu11x0*
rm -f mxu11x0.ko
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# make install
  *******************************************************************
  # MOXA UPort 1110/1130/1150/1150I USB to Serial Hub Driver v1.2 #
  #                for Linux Kernel 2.6.x                           #
  #                                                                 #
  #               release date : 03/23/2009                         #
  *******************************************************************
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5/build SUBDIRS=/root/moxa/mxu11x0/driver modules 
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [module] Error 2
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# 
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# uname -a
Linux lnx149-252 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:43 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386     GNU/Linux
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# uname -r
2.6.18-194.el5
[root@lnx149-252 driver]#
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're building this custom driver, you shall have the corresponding *kernel-devel-2.6.18-194.el5* rpm installed. Just consider installing it.

You may want to check the docs (if there are any) for this driver to see if there are any other specific dependencies/requirements for the system where it shall be built.